# Is my mobile UI too busy or just right?

Tags: interface-design, color-theory, mobile, ios, flat-design

I recently finished touching up my UI for my app, I was curious to hear some professional opinions. Is it too busy? I need to display a few things in tandem and this was my solution.

If anyone is curious, the fonts I used were Blogger San Medium and Lato Bold.

[image]

Comment: Hi James. Please have a look at our [guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682) and see whether you can make your question fit those. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it looks to busy, **no**. But how does it look when it's filled with more content? How does the text look when it's too long for the field. Consider making a worst-case-mockup, not just a best-case.

The icon you are using for the **active tab** says "map" to me. But I think you mean "near", right? You should consider that people might expect a map when they press it. And fulfilling those expectations is very important to UX.

Are the **Stars** and **feedback** related? If so they should maybe be closer together.

The third icon next to the smileys also seems to use an active color. What do i deactivate when I press it?

Generally I get the impression that you have **three competing rating systems**: feedback, stars, smileys. Plus you can probably reply as well. So yes your UI is not cluttered, but the functions you are visually conveying are confusing a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't feel too busy to me at all. I think you've got a nice hierarchy of elements going on in the header, message area, and footer. My eye scanned everything really easily.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working on this for so long, I'm glad I finally got it right.